# How to Organizing the X-axis using Plot_ly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I need help tackling this organization problem within Plotly. I searched through previous questions and while I did find similar problems, I could not find exactly what I needed or it wasn't explained in a way I could apply to my dataset.

My X-axis is supposed to be a time line between 0-13 days. The problem I am having is that Plotly organizes the axis in a way which makes days 11 and 13 come before 4-8. I also have what is called an "Initial day" in the X-axis, which might be throwing off the X-axis as a whole.

My code is this:

```
TLEXline <- plot_ly(TLEX, x = ~Time.line, y = ~Volume, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", linetype = ~Experimental.Group, color = I("black")) %>%
  layout(title = "MouseData",
         xaxis = list(title = "Time Line"),
         yaxis = list("Volume"))
```

Which creates this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `categoryorder='trace'` in the layout settings for the `xaxis`.

The [documentation](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-categoryorder) states

> By default, plotly uses "trace", which specifies the order that is
>   present in the data supplied.

but this seems to be wrong.

Without changing the layout

[image]

With changing the layout as shown below
[image]

```
library(plotly)

t <- c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "8", "10", "11", "12", "13")
vol <- c(2000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 8500)

p <- plot_ly(x = t, y = vol, type='scatter', mode = 'type', )  %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(categoryorder='trace'))
p
```